# length of string issue in assembly MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a very simple MIPS assembly code:

```
               .data
promptStr:     .asciiz "Please enter a string:"
string:        .space 120
               .text

main: 
         la $a0, promptStr
         li $v0, 4
         syscall

         la $a0, string
         li $a1, 30
         li $v0, 8
         syscall

         move $s0, $a0   #save the string in $s0 because $a0 may change         
         later by other syscalls


countLength:

         la $t0, 0($s0)

loop:
         lb   $t1, 0($t0)
         beq  $t1, $zero end

         addi $t0, $t0, 1
         j loop

end:

         la $t1, 0($s0)
         sub $t3 $t0 $t1 #$t3 now contains the length of the string

         addi $a0, $t3, 0 #print the number of characters in the string
         li $v0, 1
         syscall
```

I don't know why but it prints me always one extra. It looks very simple and obvious.
For example, for the string "aa" it prints 3. Why?
What's wrong?

Comment: You realize assembly code exists for every architecture right? Please don't make us guess at which one you're using.

Comment: sorry im new to it. its in MIPS

Comment: @JonathonReinhart
its MIPS

Comment: Presumably your input includes the terminating line feed (enter) too.

Comment: In these cases use debugger, to step over single instructions, and watch particular registers, how their value does change after each step. For input "44" you should see in the loop the `t1` to become twice `0x34` (ASCII code of character "4"), and then you expect `0` to terminate the counting and output "2" as length... so at that point something unexpected happens. By watching the register values and stepping over instructions it should be easy to tell, what went not-as-expected.